# The name Response does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor

I'm creating a Blazor web application with .Net Core and trying to save the token in the cookie. However I get the error:

> The name Response does not exist in the currect context

In all the examples that I have seen people do not face this problem. What do I have to do?

```cs
@functions {
    async Task Submit()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            User user = new User(state.user.Username, state.user.Password);
            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/adimin/token", user);
            var token = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();

            var option = new CookieOptions();
            option.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
            Response.Cookies.Append(setting, token, option);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you copy paste this error? Or is it a typo in your post? respose != response

Comment: sorry, my fault, it happend due to rush. There have to be response.

Comment: I don't think `@functions` exists in C#. please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: it is blazor framework

Comment: Your code sample is from the `blazor` app? If so, that runs in the browser. If you need to set a cookie, I suppose you should to do that on the server side...

Comment: the Response is only exist when you called from a page, not from a task

Comment: Maybe using "HttpResponse" instead of "Response" will work. source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse.cookies?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Side note: `using (var client = new HttpClient())` is a bad idea in all editions of .NET. Use `@inject`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know why Response does not exist in the current context. 
Actually there is no current context here. So no response here as well. Your "current context" here is a Blazor Component: "code behind".

1. You should present all the relevant code in your question.
2. Focus on a single issue you've got.

Let me recommend that you start learning Blazor from Microsoft doc, and when you cannot solve your issues, come here for help.
Start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 8):

This worked well to me:-

`Replace` Response with `HttpContext.Current.Response`

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

using system.web

and then write 
HttpContext.Current.Response

Comment: now it says 'HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'Current'

Comment: httpcontext is available in .net framework not in .net core